# Normalize a Vector from a struct in C

Tags: c

```
typedef struct 
{
    float x, y, z;
} VECTOR;
```

Write a function that takes a pointer to a VECTOR structure and normalizes the x, y, and z components

I realize you can normalize the Vector by getting the length and dividing x, y, and z by the length. but how would I do this with the code presented here.
Here is my attempt at this.

```
Void Norm(*VECTOR)
{
    x = x / *VECTOR.Length;
    y = y / *VECTOR.Length;
    z = z / *VECTOR.Length;
}
```

Comment: Which language is this o_O ?

Comment: Normally you would calculate the length.  `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)`

Comment: check out this link:  http://snipd.net/2d-and-3d-vector-normalization-and-angle-calculation-in-c

Comment: There's no such thing as "portable between languages" - unless you're writing an [IOCCC entry](http://www.ioccc.org/2000/tomx.c)  . Pick a language and write good code for that language!

Comment: consider using `double` precision - it may be equallty fast or faster, and give more accurate results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

typedef struct 
{
    float x, y, z;
} VECTOR;

void normalize( VECTOR* p )
{
    float w = sqrt( p->x * p->x + p->y * p->y + p->z * p->z );
    p->x /= w;
    p->y /= w;
    p->z /= w;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't work because of course w is not included in the question.

Comment: The question included some fictitious `Length`, so I am introducing my own member in its place.  Whatever you thought your `Length` was, that's what my `w` is.

Comment: I appreciate that but the question is the top part and the bottom part is my attempt at it. I believe this is a C question rather than C++

Comment: OK, in light of this, I will amend.

Comment: I am just curious why you used the variable w instead of say a L and the syntax to me is a little confusing as well.
"/=" particularly

I'd just really like to understand this thank you

Comment: I just wanted a single-letter variable, variables are lowercase by convention so 'L' was out of the question, and 'l' is not a good idea because it looks like an 'I' or a '1'.  The syntax is good old C.